# How to design an optimal trip planner

Tags: algorithm

I'm developing a trip planer program. Each city has a property called rateOfInterest. Each road between two cities has a time cost. The problem is, given the start city, and the specific amount of time we want to spend, how to output a path which is most interesting (i.e. the sum of the cities' rateOfInterest). I'm thinking using some greedy algorithm, but is there any algorithm that can guarantee an optimal path?

**EDIT** Just as @robotking said, we allow visit places multiple times and it's only interesting the first visit. We have 50 cities, and each city approximately has 5 adjacent cities. The cost function on each edge is either time or distance. We don't have to visit all cities, just with the given cost function, we need to return an optimal partial trip with highest ROI. I hope this makes the problem clearer!

Comment: You could traverse every possible path and find the one with the maximum `sum(ROI)`.

Comment: I assume you can visit each city multiple times but it is only interesting the first visit.

Comment: Could you please make your question more specified? It has some points that can't be quite worked out at the moment. Are you allowed to visit places more than once? How many cities are we talking about? If you can visit places more than once, does @robertking 's interpretation hold? If possible, could you provide an example?

Comment: yes, just like 2robertkingwe allow visit places multiple times.

Comment: yes, just as @robotking said, we allow visit places multiple times and  it's only interesting the first visit. We have 50 cities, and each city approximately has 5 adjacent cities. The cost function on each edge is either time or distance. We don't have to visit all cities, just with the given cost function, we need to return an optimal partial trip with highest ROI. Hope this makes the problem clearer :)

Comment: This is known as Prize Collecting Traveling Salesman Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very much like an instance of a TSP in a weighted manner meaning there is some vertices that are more desirable than other...

Now you could find an optimal path trying every possible permutation (using backtracking with some pruning to make it faster) depending on the number of cities we are talking about. See the TSP problem is a n! problem so after n > 10 you can forget it...

If your number of cities is not that small then finding an optimal path won't be doable so drop the idea... however there is most likely a good enough heuristic algorithm to approximate a good enough solution.

Steven Skiena recommends "Simulated Annealing" as the heuristics of choice to approximate such hard problem. It is very much like a "Hill Climbing" method but in a more flexible or forgiving way. What I mean is that while in "Hill Climbing" you always only accept changes that improve your solution, in "Simulated Annealing" there is some cases where you actually accept a change even if it makes your solution worse locally hoping that down the road you get your money back...

Either way, whatever is used to approximate a TSP-like problem is applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem, note that the decision problem version is "(where, given a length L, the task is to decide whether any tour is shorter than L)". If somebody gives me a travelling salesman problem to solve I can set all the cities to have the same rate of interest and then the decision problem is whether a most interesting path for time L actually visits all the cities and returns.

So if there was an efficient solution for your problem there would be an efficient solution for the travelling salesman problem, which is unlikely.

If you want to go further than a greedy search, some of the approaches of the travelling salesman problem may be applicable - http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.26.5150 describes "Iterated Local Search" which looks interesting, with reference to the TSP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want optimality, use a brute force exhaustive search where the leaves are the one where the time run out. As long as the expected depth of the search tree is less than `10` and worst case less than `15` you can produce a practical algorithm.

Now if you think about the future and expect your city network to grow, then you cannot ensure optimality. In this case you are dealing with a local search problem.